# What is best tool to benchmark MonetDB

Tags: monetdb

I'm currently searching for a MonetDB benchmark software. However, I'm a novice in this field and I can't find compatible benchmark tool for MonetDB. It seems like developers of MonetDB used "Xmark". However, it only supports MonetDB4 not MonetDB5. Is there any benchmark tools that supports MonetDB5?

Answer (score 0):

Xmark was the benchmark for XML databases. You might pick up TPC-H for normal database benchmarking.